# Can't Update Active Directory-Schema

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I want to update the AD-Schema with the command `Update-LapsADSchema`, however it threws an exception: "The user has insufficient access rights"

The user I'm using for this task is a member of the groups:

- schema admins
- domain admins
- enterprise admins

Comment: `The user I'm using for this task is a member of the groups` how are you validating that at the command prompt?

Comment: @GregAskew using the command `net user /domain nameofmyuser`

Comment: My own experience here suggests that it's not enough to be in these administrator groups, you actually have to elevate your privilege level via "Run as Administrator".

Comment: From an elevated command prompt where you are able to reproduce the symptom: `whoami /groups`

Comment: @tsc_chazz I have tried this already. Unfortunately it didn't work either.

Comment: @GregAskew I have tried that from an elevated command prompt. Same result. And `whoami /groups` tells me that I am a member in this groups.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you running the command(s) on the Server that holds the Schema Master FSMO role?